# Java Script code to sum 6 different field's value

Tags: javascript

[Image for required code to add value in Total field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx7UQ.png) Initially i had 4 filed to sum, but now 2 more fields are added. as per 4 fields i have below code but adding 2 more it is becoming more complex as per my knowledge.

[required sum for these 6 fileds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqyJX.png)

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.history.ChangeItemBean

// Get values from 4 custom fields
def val1 =  getCustomFieldValue("FTE US") as Double
def val2 = getCustomFieldValue("FTE OGS IND") as Double
def val3 = getCustomFieldValue("FTE OGS PHL") as Double
def val4 = getCustomFieldValue("FTE Vendor") as Double

// check both fields contain valid numeric values
if (val1 == null && val2 == null && val3 == null && val4 == null){
    return 0
}else if (val1 != null && val2 != null&& val3 != null&& val4 != null){
     return val1 + val2 + val3 + val4
}else if (val1 == null && val2 != null&& val3 != null&& val4 != null){
     return 0 + val2 + val3 + val4
}else if (val2 == null && val1 != null&& val3 != null&& val4 != null){
     return 0 + val1 + val3 + val4
}else if (val3 == null && val1 != null&& val2 != null&& val4 != null){
     return 0 + val1+ val2 + val4
}else if (val4 == null && val1 != null&& val2 != null&& val3 != null){
     return 0 + val1 + val2 + val3
}else if (val3 == null && val4 == null&& val1 != null&& val2 != null){
     return 0 + val1 + val2
}else if (val2 == null && val4 == null&& val1 != null&& val3 != null){
     return 0 + val1 + val3
}else if (val2 == null && val3 == null&& val1 != null&& val4 != null){
     return 0 + val1 + val4
}else if (val1 == null && val4 == null&& val2 != null&& val3 != null){
     return 0 + val2 + val3

}else if (val1 == null && val3 == null&& val2 != null&& val4 != null){
     return 0 + val2 + val4
}else if (val1 == null && val2 == null&& val3 != null&& val4 != null){
     return 0 + val3 + val4
}else{
    // return to some code to indicate a null value in one of the fields
 return "0"   
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that's JavaScript.

Comment: I am not sure why you have every possible sum for every condition. If you have to implement each permutation by hand, you are certainly missing some easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

Much easier put all the values into an array and then call:

```
[val1, val2, val3, val4].filter((x) => !isNaN(x)).reduce((a, b) => a + b)
```

What I'm doing is:

- use `filter` to remove "not number" elements (`!isNaN(x)`);
- use a reducer to sum all the remaining elements.

You could add all the elements you want to above array.

Comment: Thanks for your time and answering my question, i am creating a scripted field in JIRA, to sum total FTEs , if any of them is blank then consider zero, else add all the value... it would be great help if i can get the code for this........................................def val1 =  getCustomFieldValue("FTE COL") as Double
def val2 = getCustomFieldValue("FTE OGS IND") as Double
def val3 = getCustomFieldValue("FTE OGS PHL") as Double
def val4 =  getCustomFieldValue("FTE PR") as Double
def val5 =  getCustomFieldValue("FTE US") as Double
def val6 = getCustomFieldValue("FTE Vendor") as Double

Comment: Thanks @Giovanni Esposito for your answers, could you please help me to get the code for the values provided by me in above image

Comment: @AmitSingh Maybe I was not clear, I think you don't need to modify the way you are getting val1,val2... Just replace all the code in which you check if values are null with the line code I suggested and should work. If it doesn't, could you post the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript should add Null as 0, but you can make sure with a function like the one at the end here. Also, as mentioned "def" and "as Double" are not valid in Javascript. This test code correctly alerts 4.5.

```
let val1 = returnDouble();
let val2 = retNull();
let val3 = returnDouble();
let val4 = returnDouble();

alert(val1 + val2 + val3 + val4);

function retNull() {
    return(null);
}

function returnDouble () {
    return(1.5);
}

// OR to be very sure use a Conditional Operator to make Null into a 0 integer
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

function makeNullZero(value) {
    return(Null == value ? 0 : value);

}
```

It seems like the components you are importing are Java (not Javascript) https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.6.1/com/atlassian/jira/component/ComponentAccessor.html

If your variable could be assigned null, make it a Double (with a capital D) to avoid errors and convert it to zero like this:

```
     public static void main(String []args){
        Double val1 = makeNullZero(1.5);
        Double val2 = makeNullZero(null);
        
        Double sum = val1 + val2;
        System.out.println(sum);
     }
     
     static Double makeNullZero(Double val) {
         return null == val ? 0 : val;
     }
```

So for your use case:

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.history.ChangeItemBean

// Get values from 4 custom fields
Double val1 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("FTE US"));
Double val2 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("FTE OGS IND"));
Double val3 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("FTE OGS PHL"));
Double val4 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("FTE PR"));
Double val5 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("FTE COL"));
Double val6 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("FTE Vendor"));

Double sum = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4 + val5 + val6;
return sum;

static Double makeNullZero(Double val) {
    return null == val ? 0 : val;
}
```

Comment: i have to do total for below 6 field's value, whether any of them is null/blank/value.............. def val1 =  getCustomFieldValue("FTE COL") as Double
def val2 = getCustomFieldValue("FTE OGS IND") as Double
def val3 = getCustomFieldValue("FTE OGS PHL") as Double
def val4 =  getCustomFieldValue("FTE PR") as Double
def val5 =  getCustomFieldValue("FTE US") as Double
def val6 = getCustomFieldValue("FTE Vendor") as Double
FTE COL:2
FTE OGS IND:2.5
FTE OGS PHL:2
FTE PR:0
FTE US:0
FTE Vendor:0.5
FTE Total:5.0

Comment: Thanks @Bktrout47 for your answers, could you please help me to get the code for the values provided by me in above image.

Comment: @amit-singh Added some simple code with your inputs to my answer. As others mentioned above, putting the field values in an array would simplify the code. but I thought you might just want to get it working step by step at first. Please upvote my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank You So Much! it helps as per my requirement... you are awesome!

Comment: Hi Bktrout47, need one more help on below code..

Comment: Double val1 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("Benefit 1 Annual $ Amount (Run Rate) ($)"));
Double val2 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("Benefit 2 Annual $ Amount (Run Rate) ($)"));
Double val3 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("Benefit 3 Annual $ Amount (Run Rate) ($)"));
Double val4 = makeNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("Benefit 4 Annual $ Amount (Run Rate) ($)"));
Double sum = val1 + val2 + val3 + val4;
return sum;
static Double makeNullZero(Double val) {
    return null == val ? 0 : val;
}

Comment: Getting below error. -  The script could not be compiled:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script159.groovy: 5: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "$5" or bracket the value expression "5" @ line 5, column 47.
   keNullZero(getCustomFieldValue("Benefit